# Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for VARIABLE_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Creando una base de datos que es un registro de las sesiones de trabajo de una empresa donde se registra el nombre del operario, el momento de inicio de trabajo y el momento de finalización del mismo:

```
CREATE TABLE maintable(
 id_session INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 worker VARCHAR(75),
 time_start TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 time_end TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
 )
```

Al meter el código anterior en my sql workbench me da el siguiente error:

**Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'time_end'**

***¿Por qué ocurre este error y cómo lo puedo solucionar?***
Tengo la impresión de que tengo que indicarle que time_start es distinto de time_end pero no sé como hacerlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que sucede, es que las columnas del tipo TIMESTAMP declaradas con el atributo NOT NULL, no permiten valores nulos. (Debes estar trabajando con modo estricto).

Lo que yo te recomiendo, es asignarles DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

```
    CREATE TABLE maintable(
 id_session INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 worker VARCHAR(75),
 time_start TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 time_end TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
 )
```

Y actualizar el campo según corresponda.

Slds!

Answer (score 0):

El comportamiento está relacionado con la inicialización automática de TIMESTAMP y el SQL mode. No estoy seguro que versión de MySQL Server está usando (probablemente 5.7.x) por lo que recomendaría leer (disculpe pero la documentación está en Inglés):

- [5.1.10 Server SQL Modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html)
- [11.2.6 Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

específicamente lo relacionado con `NO_ZERO_IN_DATE` y `NO_ZERO_DATE`.

Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2769fa7161006c7a0d2ff9075fb17e25).